# Repaint Java - I've read many questions, but still not working

Tags: java, swing, repaint

Like in a topic, I've readed the most of all solutions for repaint() but for my code their are not working. I'm a begginer so forgive me a mess in my code..

class View.java

```
public class View extends JFrame{
public void make(){
    setSize(640,480);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Parking");
}

double x_ = MyFrame.x;
double y_ = MyFrame.y;
double odchylenie_ = MyFrame.odchylenie;
int szerokosc = 50;
int wysokosc = 30;

   public void paint(Graphics g){
       Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(-szerokosc / 2., -wysokosc / 2.,                    szerokosc, wysokosc);
       AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
       transform.translate(x_, y_);
       transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(odchylenie_));
       Shape rotatedRect = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2.draw(rotatedRect);
}
```

All I want to do to re-paint this rotatedRect with new values of x,y and odchylenie (sorry for polish variable names).

I'm calculating new variable values and using Jbutton to redraw it. 
Here is my MyFrame.class

```
public class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static double x,y,odchylenie,kat;

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        View v = new View();
        v.make();
        Fuzzy f = new Fuzzy();
        kat = f.wyjscie(x, odchylenie);
        jLabel5.setText("Kąt: " + Double.toString(kat));
        odchylenie = Fuzzy.wyliczOdchylenie(odchylenie,kat);
        jLabel8.setText("Nowe odchylenie: " + Double.toString(odchylenie));  
        x = Fuzzy.wyliczX(x, 10, kat,odchylenie);
        jLabel6.setText("Nowy x: " + Double.toString(x));
        y = Fuzzy.wyliczY(y,x, 10, kat,odchylenie);
        jLabel7.setText("Nowy y: " + Double.toString(y));
        v.repaint(); //Not works
   }
```

Instead of doing repaint(), the new window appears, and old one stays... 
I have tried to declare View v outside the button function body, but it not worked too(nothing is painting).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 3) *"I've read many questions.."* Link to 5 of them.  You are making mistakes in the current codes and I would hope at least one of those 5 covers each of the mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you override one of the `paint()` methods, you need to make a call to the super's method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    // your code goes here
}
```

Further, you should really be using `paintComponent()`, not `paint()`.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: And also i've forget to say i've tried this too... the window only changes color from white to grey...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `paint`, use `paintComponent`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(-szerokosc / 2., -wysokosc / 2.,                    szerokosc, wysokosc);
       AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
       transform.translate(x_, y_);
       transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(odchylenie_));
       Shape rotatedRect = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
       g2.draw(rotatedRect);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer the question or is it a design suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry I've forget to say that I've tried this too. When I used paintComponent the Rectangle did not appear (only empty window)

Comment: Did you call `super.paintComponents`?

Comment: @System.exit Did you mean `paintComponent()`?  `paintComponents()` (note the 's') is generally not overridden.

Comment: yes i called super.paintComponents(g) only window appear with no rectangle

Comment: @whiskeyspider I made a mistake. I retract, without the 's'. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: when i'm trying to call super.paintComponent(g) theres a Cannot find symbol error

Comment: @soncrash It is because I thought as a `JPanel`... Try to create a `JPanel` and `setContentPane` in your `View`.

Comment: So my View should be JPanel instead of JFrame? public class View extends JPanel{

Comment: Yes, and then put it into a `JFrame`, as in `make()`.

Comment: @System.exit but I can't put `setContentPane()` into make().. - cannot find sympol

Comment: `setContentPane` it's an attribute of `JFrame`. In your container frame.